# Security for ASP.NET Diagnostics page

Tags: asp.net, security, diagnostics

I'm thinking of creating a diagnostics page for an ASP.NET app, which would be mostly intended for admin use to get more information about the application for diagnosing problems.

Examples of the info the page might have :

- System.Environment.MachineName (might be useful in web farm scenarios)
- System.Environment.Version
- Environment.UserName
- database name
- current user's session ID

Some of the info on this page might be sensitive from a security perspective.
If you've done this sort of page before, what sort of security did you put on access to this page ? .

**EDIT :**

I should add - occasionally it might be useful to see this page whilst logged in as a specific (i.e. real) end user. e.g. say a problem can only be reproduced when logged in as a particular user. Being able to see the diagnostics page for that user might be useful. e.g. knowing the current session ID might be helpful for debugging.

**EDIT 2 :**

I'm starting to think that this diagnostics page should in fact be two different pages. One to display stuff which is the same for all users (e.g. database name, CLR version), and another for stuff which can vary by session (e.g. browser info, session ID).
Then you could lock down security more for the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've added this sort of page before (and found it useful). The security was pretty simple: the page contained a password form. The server-side code checked this password against a configured value and, if correct, displayed the real content and set a value in the user's session to say that they've been authenticated as a developer, so that they're not prompted again next time.

I suppose there was also a little security by obscurity, since the URL of the page wasn't published anywhere.

I was also careful not to reveal anything *really* sensitive on the page. For example, it allowed viewing our application config values, but masked out anything with "password" in it - hey, if we really want to see the password we can open a remote desktop session to the server.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a couple of other ways you could do this:

- If your web application has user authentication, restrict access to this page by checking that the user is flagged as an administrator or belongs to some kind of admin role.
- Use a simple `if (Request.IsLocal) ...` type check, though the downside of this is that you still have to connect to the server and browse the website locally - which might not always be possible.  However, this does still have the benefit of being able to easily view key system settings.

Personally, I've used a combination of both methods where a local request always allows access, and non-local requests require an admin user - eg. `if (!Request.IsLocal && !IsAdminUser()) throw new SecurityException()`.

Also, I'm in agreement with Evgeny - be careful not to reveal anything *really* sensitive on this page (such as application connection strings or passwords).

Answer (score 0):

use forms authentication and setup a user or two with access to that page.  that way you can change passwords and revoke access once the site is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a robust solution for your error page. I would take a look at open source projects like Elmah (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for a good example of a robust error page which includes configurable security. To give you an idea, here is a [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx) on configuring Elmah which takes you through setting up the security. The security I have tested allows me to use my domain credentials to login.